# Maven enforcer rule for finding dependencies that mix Java EE and Jakarta EE

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jakarta-migration, maven-enforcer-plugin

When starting to convert apps and libraries to Jakarta EE, is there any Maven enforcer rule or way to check the build time classpath for dependencies that might be mixing the old Java EE APIs?

I know about the one time conversion tools like open rewrite or [Eclipse Transformer](https://github.com/eclipse/transformer), but I want to put something in place to identify if something "sneaks" back in.

Comment: You could use https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html ?

Comment: Sort of? But I'd have to know if it was a java EE vs jakarta ee project before time. I was hoping more for a "Either is correct, just not both at the same time. No mixing" type of rule.

It's also more difficult since the the classes can be repackaged in so many jars. I was wondering there was was like a classpath inspection option.